# RoR - Polyline in GoogleMaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I'm using Ym4r and want to add a polyline to my map.

This works:

```
polyline = GPolyline.new([[27.4037755983,89.4263076782],[27.5155793659,89.3245124817]],"#ff0000",3,1.0)
@map.record_init @map.add_overlay(polyline)
```

But this doesn't:

```
polystring = "[27.4037755983,89.4263076782],[27.5155793659,89.3245124817]"
polyline = GPolyline.new([polystring],"#ff0000",3,1.0)
@map.record_init @map.add_overlay(polyline)
```

Any idea why?
Regards
Arwed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code given it shows that GPolyline.new accept 1st parameter as an array (aray of array)  so try this

```
polystring = [[27.4037755983,89.4263076782],[27.5155793659,89.3245124817]]
polyline = GPolyline.new(polystring,"#ff0000",3,1.0)
@map.record_init @map.add_overlay(polyline)
```

also

```
   polystring = "[27.4037755983,89.4263076782],[27.5155793659,89.3245124817]"
   arr1= [polystring]
   arr2= [[27.4037755983,89.4263076782],[27.5155793659,89.3245124817]]

then arr1[0] = "[27.4037755983,89.4263076782],[27.5155793659,89.3245124817]" where as 
     arr2[0] = [27.4037755983,89.4263076782]
```